# div background image not showing while printing in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, html, media-queries

I am creating certificate, In which I am using div background image. All things working properly. At the time of printing div background image is not displaying.Div background not displaying not even in pdf.
I am using this media query .

```
@media print
{
    * {-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;}
    .clsprint
    {
    background-image:url(cert.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this Add style in Js while Priniting

```
   `var divElements = document.getElementById("divAlterationPrint").innerHTML;

    var w = window.open('', 'Placement Form', 'width=860,scrollbars=yes');
    w.document.write('<html><head><title>Placement Form</title>');
    var sdf = '<style>#divId {background-image:url(cert.jpg);}</style>';
    w.document.write(sdf);
    w.document.write('</head><body>');
    w.document.write(divElements);
    w.document.write('</body></html>');
    w.print();
    w.document.close();`
```